# Which features are not supported when GPU rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, compatibility

This question would seem to have a straightforward answer, but after reading through the [Blender Manual's section about GPU Rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#introduction), and also searching elsewhere online, I have not been able to find a list of which features are not supported when rendering with a GPU.

I remember that Open Shading Language is not supported, but I'm sure there are other unsupported features that I either don't know about or have forgotten about.

Does anyone know if there is a resource page available somewhere where I can get a list that makes this clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand what you are looking for, the [Blender manual seems to have a pretty thorough list of supported features per device](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html).

As of current Blender 2.78, this list includes all supported computing hardware types, like CPU, GPU, OpenCL, or CUDA; and the available , experimental, and unsupported features for each of them, like motion blur, hair, volume, smoke/fire, subsurface scattering (SSS), Open Shading Language (OSL), CMJ Sampling, Branched Path integrator, and displacement subdivision.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Somehow I totally overlooked it. My mistake! Thank you.

Comment: Actually it seems to be kind of hard to come by for some reason. I posted it here a few days ago and had to [dig up my old answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76211/cycles-sss-not-working-on-amd-radeon-gpu/76216#76216), because I could not find it again using google somehow.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one who had trouble finding it. Probably because I searched "blender unsupported GPU rendering" instead of something like "blender render features". Hopefully this post will also be useful to others who are searching.

Comment: Added some more textual data to make it easier to find

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the more CUDA you have, and the more Vram (2-4-6-8-12GO) the more it will make the difference, however, don't forget that textures HighRes (4K,6K or 8K) are extremely heavy and if you use your GPU, then it will crash or abort if you don't have enough Vram, which would not happen if you use the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for this reminder about the memory consumption of textures. I didn't know about the increased probability of crashing/aborting when using a GPU.