# question about GPU simulations

Tags: baking, gpu

I have bought a new laptop and I am using blender now for a couple weeks. IS it normal that blender uses only the CPU for baking phisics? And is there a way to use the GPU for baking?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76557/which-features-are-not-supported-when-gpu-rendering/76562#76562

Comment: Yes it is normal to just use cpu for simulation. There is no way I know of to use gpu